# Манипуляция с выборкой из List<T> с помощью LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

По условию задачи произвольный `List<T>` имеет атрибут `id`. Необходимо выбрать и записать в переменную `i` максимальное значение атрибута `id`. How to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например использовать [функцию Max](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb535031(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
list.Max(el=>el.Id)
```